# The "bird" process keeps running at high % CPU and writes lots of data. How do I fix this?

Tags: icloud, cpu, activity-monitor

I'm running **macOS 13.4** (22F66) on a **MacBook Pro 16" (2019)** and the process **bird** (which seems to be iCloud-related) keeps running at very high CPU utilization. It also [makes Xcode unresponsive](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731734) until I force quit **bird**, after which Xcode resumes operating but bird immediately restarts and shoots back up to high CPU utilization.

It also seems to write a ton of data, as seen by the *Bytes Written* value in Activity Monitor relentlessly climbing.

My ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.bird cache is merely 160 Bytes large. The size of this cache is not my issue, the CPU hogging of the process is.

[image: bird process takes up 95% of CPU]

Now I've seen [elsewhere](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/441777/351157) that I can see the log via

```
brctl log -w --shorten
```

but I don't know how to interpret that log, and despite many mentions of **bird** taking up a lot of resources, I can't find any thread in which someone actually *resolved* this problem.

I'd appreciate any help here. How do I make **bird** chill out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is com.apple.bird? Why does it grow so big?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220007/what-is-com-apple-bird-why-does-it-grow-so-big)

Comment: Not really. My `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.bird` cache is merely 160 Bytes large. The size of this cache is not my issue, the CPU utilisation of the process is.

Comment: Could that help you? https://iboysoft.com/news/mac-process-bird-high-cpu.html

Comment: You've still got 89% CPU Idle, according to that graph. The CPU % is per core, of which you've got 12. There may well be a problem, but it's not for want of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution for problems with iCloud processes is to sign out from and back in to your AppleID.

Comment: Maybe this should have been posted as a comment: "Have you tried signing out and back in to your Apple ID?"